# Pi stopped booting after losing power - can it be recovered

Tags: pi-3b+, power, boot-issues, recovery

I have had a pi running as a Bluetooth link to a meat-curing machine and it's been awesome! The thing has run without issues for like 45 days.

Well today I decided to move it to a new room and so I powered it down, moved it and plugged it in and now the darn thing won't boot.

The green light flashes 2-4 times (it's hard to tell as it flashes pretty fast), and if I plug it into a monitor I get the rainbow screen. It does grab an IP address from my router which I find odd and holds and ssh tries to connect but eventually times out.

I had installed Raspbian using a good SD card and using the power supply sold by Raspberry Pi.

I'd hate to lose what was on the card, is there a way to:

1. Recover the Pi so it can boot again?
2. Get whatever was in my home folder off and on to a new Pi.

I have been reading a ton but it seems that there is not a ton of info on recovering if the start.elf can't be read.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The best option is to restore from your backup. You could try [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)
 Otherwise the next best option is a fresh install to a new SD Card, and you may be able to recover files from the old card.

Comment: I have gone through the boot sticky and had no luck :( I get what looks like the start.elf isn't loading.